# Prevent space after pre-processor macro replacement

Tags: c++11

I am curious if it is possible to eliminate the space that pre-processor inserts/retains (?) after replacing macro token

```
//Code

#define s std::

void PrintMatches2(std::string str, s regex reg)



//Output

void PrintMatches2(std::string str, std:: regex reg)

/*---------------------------------------^----------Want to eliminate space here*/
```

TIA

EDIT: Don't understand the reason for down-vote. Question is clear, well formatted.

Comment: Just curious, what do you want it for?

Comment: @javaLover Hey there. Nothing really, I am just curious. Might turn out useful one day when the syntax requires it not to be present.

Comment: not with the syntax `s regex`, there is just no reason for the preprocessor to mess with the existing space

Comment: What is the harm of the space?   How useful if the space is removed?  Is it IDE's related reason, perhaps?

Comment: @kmdreko Yeah, I tried to remove that space somehow by trying token name combinations, but did not work. The token won't be detected without the space between token_name and regex.

Comment: @javaLover The first thing that came to mind was generating custom names like XYZ_macro. A space there would defeat the purpose. A function macro might be possible solution. I did not understand what you mean by IDE's reason. Thanks.

Comment: In Visual Studio, there is an expensive plug-in named Resharper, it can convert Macro to real C++ code and beautify the code automatically.(e.g. remove space, insert new line).   I misunderstood that you wanted to remove space just to beautify your converted code.

Comment: How would you expect to remove a space since you already have a space after `s` in `s regex s`? Also you should avoid using macros as much as possible. In a case like this, it is far more better to write `std::regex` than `s regex`. You need to write code that people understand instead of making code hard to read to make a few less keystroke.

Comment: @javaLover Thanks, I don't use visual studio but will look into it

Comment: @Phil1970 I know the space in ```s regex``` is being retained with fidelity, but if I remove it as to not have it, then the token ```s``` is not recognized by pre-processor. Yes sir, I shall keep the clarity issue in mind. Here, I was just going through an example code to learn, and got curious about the use of macros. (motivated initially by less keystrokes though) Thanks

Comment: I am not sure if this would help :-  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a48c248acb2441d8

Comment: @javaLover Tried your solution. It still inserts keeps the succeeding space.

Comment: May you provide (coliru) MCVE?  If possible ....

Comment: @javaLover MCVE? I am not familiar. I tried your code on https://godbolt.org/ with -E compiler flag to generate "pre-processed" file.

Comment: MCVE = https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example . It would be even better if you also should show the reason that make you want to remove the space in that MCVE code.  Godbolt's link to your code will help too.

Comment: @javaLover Thanks for the idea. I got it to work without the spaces ```#define MAC(x) std::                                                                                                 
std::cout << MAC(a)regex;```

Comment: I still don't fully understand your problem though, but congratulation.  Your solution is ugly and may induce headache in future, but it might be good enough if used sparingly.

Comment: @javaLover Yeah, it works but renders the code hard to understand. Will stick to full-form.

Comment: do you know that you can use `using namespace std;`?  More example here : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice/  .  It is a bad practice but work very well in some boring cases.

Comment: @javaLover Yes sir, I am making habit of explicitly stating std::, w/o using directive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @javaLover suggested in his code, it was possible to collapse the macro token and subsequent code using a macro function. (It gets detected)

```
//Code

#define s() std::

void PrintMatches2(std::string str, s()regex reg)



//Output

void PrintMatches2(std::string str, std::regex reg)
```